# How can I have different values for a set of same properties depending on value outside in constant objects?

Tags: javascript, object, constants

I am doing some kind of a skill overview, where you have different stuff for each skill level, ranging from Level 1 to 10.

```
props = {
    name: 'N/A',
    skillType: 'N/A',
    level: {
        1: {
            skillPoints: 0,
            mp: 0,
            attackPower: 0,
            effect: 0,
            requiredLevel: 0,
            castTime: {
                fixed: 0,
                variable: 0,
                total: 0
            },
            cooldown: {
                fixed: 0,
                variable: 0,
                total: 0,
            },
            duration: 0,
            attackEnemyNumber: 0,
            description: ''
        },
    },
    weaponType: '',
    posX: 0,
    posY: 0
}
```

The issue now here is that I'd like to have the same values

```
        skillPoints: 0,
        mp: 0,
        attackPower: 0,
        effect: 0,
        requiredLevel: 0,
        castTime: {
            fixed: 0,
            variable: 0,
            total: 0
        },
        cooldown: {
            fixed: 0,
            variable: 0,
            total: 0,
        },
        duration: 0,
        attackEnemyNumber: 0,
        description: ''
```

for every level from 0 to 10, but not exactly the same, as I might need to adjust the skillPoints you need to spend, or the attack power, the mp or other properties.

So I don't want to take every property under '1: {}' and copy it over to make a '2: {}' with the same properties. Is there a way to achieve that? Not sure if a constant object is a good way to do it anyway. But that would make stuff a lot easier...

Comment: You could have a `default:` level that contains the default values for all the keys. Then the other levels can specify only the differences from the default, and you merge the two dictionaries before using it.

Comment: You could write a function that returns the skills object based on the passed level. Then do `props.level["2"] = generateSkills(2);` or something.